# Does "yield" cast lambdas to procs?

Tags: ruby, lambda, yield, proc

I'm learning Ruby, and while testing the behaviour of procs and lambdas, I wrote this code:

```
def test_f(&a_block)
  puts "in test_f"
  yield 7
  puts "still in test_f"
end

def test_f_2(&a_block)
  puts "in test_f_2"
  a_block.call(7)
  puts "still in test_f_2"
end

lam = lambda do |i|
  puts "lambda #{i}"
  return "lambda #{i}"
end

test_f_2(&lam)
test_f(&lam)
```

The result of running this is:

```
in test_f_2
lambda 7
still in test_f_2
in test_f
lambda 7
test.rb:17: in 'block in <main>': unexpected return <LocalJumpError>
        from test.rb:3:in 'test_f'
        from poop.rb:21:in '<main>'
```

I have two questions from this:

1. Does this mean that using `yield` 'casts' the lambda into a proc, since it is only when using yield that attempting to return causes an error?
2. Under what circumstances is it not permitted to return from a proc?

I've read that "it's not possible to call a proc containing a return when the creating context no longer exists" but the context here is global so it doesn't make sense to me to say that the creating context for `lam` no longer exists. However, enclosing the entire creating of `lam` and calls of the test functions within another function prevents any error message from appearing, which leads me to conclude that the criterion at play is that any call to a proc containing a return must be from within a context from which you can return.

Am I right?

Comment: BTW, your code works fine for me, no errors. ruby 2.1.1

Comment: Updating my Ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.1.5 has fixed the problem for me. I'm not sure whether this is a bugfix or a change in intentional functionality, although I'm inclined to think it's a bugfix given that I've read in several places that **yield** is "syntactic sugar" for **call** so there shouldn't be any difference in behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this was a spec change in 2.0. Lambdas `return` from themselves, `Proc`s and blocks return from the method. This leaves an ambiguity: what about lambdas which are converted to blocks using the unary prefix `&` operator? Shall they behave like lambdas or like blocks? Apparently, matz changed his mind between 1.9 and 2.1. You can probably dig up the corresponding issue on http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/ or the discussion on the ruby-core or ruby-dev mailinglist.